# How do I detect if a button is clicked while holding shift in Java Eclipse AWT?

Tags: java, eclipse, awt

I'm trying to make a X and O game in Java but I need right click to count as X and left to count as O

Comment: First, let me apologize for you having to use AWT, it sucks. Second, you create an implementation of `MouseListener` which overrides the `mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)` method, and you interrogate `e.getButton()` to see if it's `MouseEvent.BUTTON1` for left-click or `MouseEvent.BUTTON2` for right-click.

Comment: In addition to the comment above, I recommend making an array to store all of the buttons pressed. This way you can run a check similar to **if(keys[Key.SHIFT] == true)**.

Comment: The title seems unrelated to the question.  Ask you asking how to distinguish the left and right mouse buttons, or are you asking how to determine whether the Shift key is held down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so first of all you will need to implement the `MouseListener` interface. You can either have your main class implement `MouseListener`, or attach a generic implementation to a `JPanel` via `addMouseListener()`. The latter method is described below:

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel {

    public MyPanel() {
        // ...
        this.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
                    // Handle left-click
                } else if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON2) {
                    // Handle right-click
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

You can also check `e.isShiftDown()` to see if the Shift key is being held.